# Azure deployment fails EF .NET 6

Tags: .net, azure, deployment

I created my deployment profile on Visual Studio, have added my connection string and everything but I get an http 500 error when accessing my azure deployed ASP.NET Core 6 application.

In the publishing settings there is an Entity Framework migrations setting which is failing:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext list --json
```

> More than one project was found in the current working directory. Use the --project option.

It does not seem to retrieve the migrations although there is just one in my `Project.DataAccess` solution.

Recreated the AzureApp Service deployment - did nothing.

Added all the IP addresses in app services in the application Firewall - did nothing

Removed .csproject files duplicates - Solved the error in the publishing settings.

Checked Application Insights - Got  `The 'AppId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'AppId')` which fails from this method `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookOptions.Validate`

Comment: Are you able to see if your schema was successfully deployed to the database by connecting to the database with i.e. Azure Data Studio? Also you could turn on App Insights and look at the Failures tab (give it a few minutes for data to be available after a given failure) and it should have more information about the specific error. If you can post the actual error message, it will help diagnose the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: Found the error in application insights `System.InvalidOperationException:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.ExecuteHostingStartups (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX)`

Answer (score 0):

Glad @*dimitri* that you have solved the issue with the following steps:

1. Removing the `.csproj` duplicate files.
2. Finding the method that causes failing using Application Insights.

In General, Http Error 500 in the .NET 6 EF Project to Azure means:

1. There could be issues in Configuration of Azure App Service or with the .NET 6 Runtime, dependencies.
2. Review the Configuration Settings thoroughly in Azure App Service and logs for the error messages and traces.
3. There is an option in the Azure App service that provides more insights about any Http Errors if detected.

Azure Portal > App Service > Diagnose and Solve problems >

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer thanks to @Paul. I had setup environment variables which could not be found for obvious reasons. Replaced them in my Program.cs and it works fine.